# iOS how can I combine dozens of UIImages into a single frame of video/animation?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, uiimage, avfoundation

I have a large image, like jigsaw puzzle which is broken into smaller chunks. Each chunk has it's own UIImage with transparent background, so only the piece is visible. If all images are drawn at once, the transparent pieces allow other image pieces to show through, so the entire image is visible.

**How can I arbitrarily combine any number of chunks and fade them in/out on screen?** For example, given 100 chunks, I want to draw 50 of them on screen and have this transition appear smooth as in chunks fading in/out.

What a good way of combining arbitrary number of images into a single frame?

- Can this be done with simply superimposing 100 UIViews on top of each other, each potentially animating UIImage fading in/out?
- Is AVFoundation a better solution - writing to a pixel buffer?
- Can Metal or SpriteKit handle this kind of task?

Comment: Sprite kit can handle this.  One good way is each puzzle piece is a node,  and when the 2 chucks combine, you make one node a child of the other node,  then when you have a 3rd piece,  you do can add the node, and all off the children to the new node, so on, so forth

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's a great suggestion, I forgot that sprite kit can have children nodes

Comment: You can do the same approach with UIView's but it is nice to have Metal working for you